# Get out of range count for every column in a table

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to get the out of range values for all columns in a table.
First I get the Out of Range Max and Min based on below code and then try to loop through all the records in the table to get the count of the records for every column which are out of range. The below function works good when the table size is small however when the table size is huge in billions it takes long time has it check each and every record. Is their any better way to get the out of range count when the table size is huge.

```py
out_of_range_max_value = spark_df.select([(F.round(F.mean(F.col(c).cast('int')),0) + 3* F.round(F.stddev(F.col(c).cast('int')),0)).alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns if dict(spark_df.dtypes)[c] not in ('timestamp', 'string', 'date','array<string>')])

out_of_range_min_value = spark_df.select([(F.round(F.mean(F.col(c).cast('int')),0) - 3* F.round(F.stddev(F.col(c).cast('int')),0)).alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns if dict(spark_df.dtypes)[c] not in ('timestamp', 'string', 'date','array<string>')])

df = spark_df.agg(*(F.count(F.when((F.col(c).cast('int') > out_of_range_pdfNA[c].astype(int).values.tolist()[0]) | (F.col(c).cast('int') < out_of_range_pdfNA[c].astype(int).values.tolist()[1]), c)).alias(c)  for c in spark_df.columns if dict(spark_df.dtypes)[c] not in ('timestamp', 'string', 'date','array<string>') ))
```